# On macOS, what is /var/db/uuidtext?

Tags: mac, var, hexidecimal

My Macbook Pro has a folder `/var/db/uuidtext`

What do the hexidecimal numbers for the subfolders represent, and what is the `dsc` subfolder?

```
James-MacBook-Pro-4:~ jamespedersen$ ls /var/db/uuidtext
00  0C  18  24  30  3C  48  54  60  6C  78  84  90  9C  A8  B4  C0  CC  D8  E4  F0  FC
01  0D  19  25  31  3D  49  55  61  6D  79  85  91  9D  A9  B5  C1  CD  D9  E5  F1  FD
02  0E  1A  26  32  3E  4A  56  62  6E  7A  86  92  9E  AA  B6  C2  CE  DA  E6  F2  FE
03  0F  1B  27  33  3F  4B  57  63  6F  7B  87  93  9F  AB  B7  C3  CF  DB  E7  F3  FF
04  10  1C  28  34  40  4C  58  64  70  7C  88  94  A0  AC  B8  C4  D0  DC  E8  F4  dsc
05  11  1D  29  35  41  4D  59  65  71  7D  89  95  A1  AD  B9  C5  D1  DD  E9  F5
06  12  1E  2A  36  42  4E  5A  66  72  7E  8A  96  A2  AE  BA  C6  D2  DE  EA  F6
07  13  1F  2B  37  43  4F  5B  67  73  7F  8B  97  A3  AF  BB  C7  D3  DF  EB  F7
08  14  20  2C  38  44  50  5C  68  74  80  8C  98  A4  B0  BC  C8  D4  E0  EC  F8
09  15  21  2D  39  45  51  5D  69  75  81  8D  99  A5  B1  BD  C9  D5  E1  ED  F9
0A  16  22  2E  3A  46  52  5E  6A  76  82  8E  9A  A6  B2  BE  CA  D6  E2  EE  FA
0B  17  23  2F  3B  47  53  5F  6B  77  83  8F  9B  A7  B3  BF  CB  D7  E3  EF  FB
Jamess-MacBook-Pro-4:~ jamespedersen$
```

I'm running `macOS High Sierra 10.13.6`

Thanks in advance,

James Pedersen

Comment: seems to be a good description here: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/10/10/inside-the-macos-log-logd-and-the-files-that-it-manages/

Comment: The URL in the comments provides an explanation.

Comment: Can I ask a second question? Do you know of a way to decode tracev3 files so that I can look at their contents?

Answer (score 0):

Text from the [page linked by toppk](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/10/10/inside-the-macos-log-logd-and-the-files-that-it-manages/), dated 2017-10-10 and about macOS Sierra:

> Apple’s grand design... fills a single unified log with many hundreds or thousands of log entries every minute. As Apple’s team stated in their 2016 presentation “we want as much logging on all the time as possible”.

> Log contents are stored as tracev3 files – an undocumented compressed binary format – in /var/db/diagnostics/Persist/ and /var/db/diagnostics/Special/. Other folders in `/var/db/diagnostics/` and `/var/db/uuidtext/` contain **ancillary information for those logs**.

> `/var/db/uuidtext/` contains a series of folders, named 00 to FF, each containing files named by UUID for *specific* log events, which extend beyond normal log entries. **These include crash events and other items which overflow single line entries in the log.** There is another folder named `dsc` which contains similar files.